# Display the first char in a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I am making a simple learning game where a number is generated and the user will have to enter the word. The problem is Im trying to get a hint button working basically when the user clicks the hint button a message box will display the first character of the string which is in the array.

Here is a example of what my array looks like.

```
static string[] numberList = { "one","two", "Three","four","five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if the number is 2 and the strings are always in that order, then you can do

```
var firstletter = numberList[2-1][0];
```

That will get you a Char. If you want that also as string then do

```
firstletter.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks this worked so if I want the  'T' in Three I would just do var firstletter = numberList[3 - 1][0];

Comment: @Eire remember to mark this answer as answer. if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

just like this

```
var first = numberList[2-1][0];
first.ToString();
```

Comment: You can index directly into the string, so there's really no need for the CharArray operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is optimized, but I like using substring() because it's very obvious what I want.

```
    numberlist[i-1].Substring(0, 1);
```

where 'i' is the number you are looking for (subtract 1 because arrays use a 0-based index)